# How to extract a value from a string column using hive

Tags: regex, replace, hive, hql

I need to extract a field from a string column using hive

```
Input:  [{"name":"MANAGER"}]
Output:    MANAGER
```

I was able to fetch the record using the below regular expression, but I am not able to remove `]` from the output.

Query built:

```
select split(regexp_replace('([{"name":"MANAGER"}])','^\\(|\\)$|[{"}]',''),': *')[1];
```

Output obtained:

```
MANAGER]
```

Could you please help  me to remove the `]` from the output and get only `MANAGER` in this example using hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can atually parse this with `get_json_object` function as the string you shared is a JSON string:

```
select get_json_object(regexp_replace('[{"name":"MANAGER"}]', '[\\[\\]]', ''), '$.name')
```

See the documentation:

> `get_json_object`
> A limited version of JSONPath is supported:
>
> - `$` : Root object
> - `.` : Child operator
> - `[]` : Subscript operator for array
> - `*` : Wildcard for []
>
> Syntax not supported that's worth noticing:
>
> - `:` Zero length string as key
> - `..` : Recursive descent
> - `@` : Current object/element
> - `()` : Script expression
> - `?()` : Filter (script) expression.
> - `[,]` : Union operator
> - `[start:end.step]` : array slice operator

Comment: Thank you ,I got the answer get_json_object(regexp_replace('[{"name":"MANAGER"}]', '[\\[\\]]', ''), '$.name')

Comment: I understand you have two backslashes in ``[\\[\\]]``